# Is there a way to make Visual Studio assume a value for a #define?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, preprocessor-directive

I am using a #define in one header that is defined in another header.  Sometimes Visual Studio decides that #define exists and it colors my code as if it will be compiled in.  Sometimes it decides that it doesn't know what the #define is and it colors my code such that it will be compiled out.  The only problem here is ONLY how Visual Studio presents my code, the code works as intended.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to assume this #define exists (and is 1)?

I know I can turn off this coloring option entirely, but I like the way it normally works.  I can also quickly define it at the top of my file to change the coloring, but then I need to remember to remove it before committing my code.  I did try checking if it was undefined and, if so, defining it. I was thinking that it would always be 1 or 0 and so never undefined.  This solved my coloring issue, but actually found places where it was undefined and resulted in compile errors.

Comment: You could set the define in your compiler settings.

Comment: Intellisense is not foolproof.  Don't change your code just because some color looks nice or not.

Comment: May be 'rescan solution' (under Project in menu) helps

Comment: Any form of adding the define has the same issue of needing to remember to remove it before actually compiling/committing.

I liked the Rescan idea, sadly it had no effect.

Comment: If the #define is only needed in the header, you can undefine it at the end of the header so that it doesn't possibly collide with the same #define in another header.